# Can one select a class hero if more than one are available?

Tags: hearthstone

I don't have a second hero for any class, yet.
What happens when I fulfill the requirements for a second class hero? Will the new hero replace the old one so that the old one is gone forever? Or can I select somehow which class hero I would like to use in a game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to "My Collection" you can look at card backs and heroes that you have and select the one that you want from there.